# Arranging Input Boxes (selectInput / numericInput etc...) dynamically in columns in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am taking significant variables from ML model(.rda file),putting them as `numericInput` box or `selectInput` Option menu in the UI page. I am getting each Input in different row. I want it as two columns in a row. How can I do that? I am getting it as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pf2V.png)

Below is the code which I want to modify.

```
 model <- reactive({readRDS(input$Load_model$datapath)})
  temp_col <- reactive({colnames(model()$model)})
  temp_no_col <- reactive({ncol(model()$model)})

  abc <- reactive(lapply(model()$model, class))
  process <- eventReactive(input$show_fields, {
    lapply(1:(temp_no_col()), function(i) {
        if(abc()[i] == "numeric" ) {
          numericInput(temp_col()[i], label = temp_col()[i],value = 0)
        }
        else if(abc()[i] == "factor") {
          selectInput(temp_col()[i], label = temp_col()[i],choices = unique(model()$model[i]))
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Please see the [shiny layout guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html). Especially the section 'Grid Layout' and the `column()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ismirsehregal says in the comments, you need to take a look at the shiny layout guide. You are creating the inputs programmaticaly, with `lapply`, so you need to dispatch the inputs created into two columns, something like this:

```
process <- eventReactive(input$show_fields, {
  inputs_temp <- lapply(1:(temp_no_col()), function(i) {
    if(abc()[i] == "numeric" ) {
      numericInput(temp_col()[i], label = temp_col()[i],value = 0)
    }
    else if(abc()[i] == "factor") {
      selectInput(temp_col()[i], label = temp_col()[i],choices = unique(model()$model[i]))
    }
  })

  shiny::tagList(
    shiny::fluidRow(
      # odd cols column
      shiny::column(6, inputs_temp[1:length(inputs_temp) %% 2 != 0]),
      # even cols column
      shiny::column(6, inputs_temp[1:length(inputs_temp) %% 2 == 0])
    )
  )
}
```

But note that you didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so I couldn't test the accuracy of the answer. If you edit the question with an small working example of your app, I can tweak and edit my answer to work with it.

Comment: Working fine, Thanks

Comment: But it is taking column from the Right side of page, Can it be dome from left

Comment: Please, edit your question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your app, at least a minimal example working. If not, there is nothing more I can do as I can't test what is your problem.